# c#: Error on running the code

Tags: c#, sql-server

While running the code after successful compilation, I have the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'End'.

Though the code is well formatted but have the error.
Someone, please help me to rectify the problem. My code is below;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Order
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection ABC = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=iPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NML;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        //SqlDataReader dataRead = new SqlDataReader();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ABC.Open();
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_REC(Qcode,Warp,Ply,Blend,TEnds,Warp1,Weft,End,Pick,,Width,Weave1,Weave2,TL) Values('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox11.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox13.Text + "','" + textBox14.Text + "')";
            command.Connection = ABC;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ABC.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY");
            textBox2.Clear();
            textBox3.Clear();
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox6.Clear();
            textBox7.Clear();
            textBox8.Clear();
            textBox9.Clear();
            textBox10.Clear();
            textBox11.Clear();
            textBox12.Clear();
            textBox13.Clear();
            textBox14.Clear();
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            command.Connection = ABC;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use parameters when passing values into queries.  Munging query strings can lead to inexplicable syntax errors -- and make the code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here in the insert query. You are using two time coma where it should be only one.

```
,End,Pick,,Width,
```

Comment: also `End` is a reserve word and thus needs to be escaped

Answer (score 2):

Your code have multiple problems in it:

1. You are concatenating strings with user inputs to create sql statements. This is a security hazard since it's an open door for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should always use parameters.
2. You are using form level variables for classes that implements the `IDisposable` interface. While sometimes that can't be avoided, this is not one of those times.
3. You are using SQL reserved words for at least one column name (`end`). This should be avoided, but in case it's too late to change the column name, you should wrap it in square brackets (`[end]`).
4. You have a couple of commas (as noted in Dalvinder Singh's answer) where there should be just one comma.

I would suggest the following alternative:

```
var success = false;
var connectionString = @"Data Source=iPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NML;Integrated Security=True";
var sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_REC(Qcode,Warp,Ply,Blend,TEnds,Warp1,Weft,[End],Pick,Width,Weave1,Weave2,TL) Values(@Qcode, @Warp, @Ply, @Blend, @TEnds, @Warp1, @Weft, @End, @Pick, @Width, @Weave1, @Weave2, @TL)";
using(var ABC = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, ABC))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Qcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Warp", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Ply", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
        // ....
        // I'll let you fill in the rest of the parameters...
        // ....

        try
        {
            ABC.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            success = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Do something with this exception! write to log, for instance.

        }
    }
}
if (success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DATA SAVED SUCCESSFULLY");
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox3.Clear();
    textBox4.Clear();
    textBox5.Clear();
    textBox6.Clear();
    textBox7.Clear();
    textBox8.Clear();
    textBox9.Clear();
    textBox10.Clear();
    textBox11.Clear();
    textBox12.Clear();
    textBox13.Clear();
    textBox14.Clear();
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```